# groff: How can I place punctuation after a link generated with the PDF_WWW_LINK mom macro?

Tags: pdf, groff

I am trying to include a link to an online web resource using the groff mom macros. Below is a minimal reproducible example of my problem:

```
Here is some text with a
.PDF_WWW_LINK https://unix.stackexchange.com "link" SUFFIX ,
where the link should be followed by a comma.
```

The intent is for this to render with a comma after the link, but no comma is generated:

[image: what is rendered]

What was desired was for there to be a comma between the words "link" and "where".

I believed putting the `SUFFIX ,` at the end would work, but putting it at the end appears not to work.

How can I place punctuation after a link?

Comment: This post follows the idea of [sharing your knowledge Q&A style](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SUFFIX ,` must come **before** the text to display for the link:

```
Here is some text with a
.PDF_WWW_LINK https://unix.stackexchange.com SUFFIX , "link"
where the link should be followed by a comma.
```

How this appears in the output PDF:

[image: output render]